# AC wall outlet to charge Super/Ultra Caps

Tags: supercapacitor

Can a super/ultra capacitor be charged from an AC outlet?

Comment: You can't charge a capacitor with AC.

Comment: You only need to plug some device between those two

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. You need a circuit in between to assure a proper loading. Normally, a DC current source may work. Otherwise, without current limitation, you may risk to destroy the supercap.

Comment: Also you need to limit the voltage on the caps as it rises during the charging process.